# Php if($var) used to work

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I have som code for a website, that used to work fine with. I want to check if a variable or session is set. I used the following code:

```
if ($_GET['something']){ //Do something }
```

Now i try to install it on a local server, at i get a error code, saying that there is an undefined index.

It requires me to do:

```
if (isset($_GET['']) { //Do something }
```

Can i make a quick fix for this, as i don't want to change the code so many places?

Comment: try if (isset($_GET['something']))

Comment: Then `something` is not a get-parameter (ie. in the query string) on the "failing server" for that request then. It's most likely just a different request/URL missing said GET parameter. Solution: check for if the key *exists* before using it.. or supply a valid query string and otherwise ignore such notices..

Comment: The `isset` is the fix. It's the best way to go about your business

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't get the error before, because your error_reporting and/or display_error settings were set too forgiving. Your first snippet *is* attempting to access a value in an array that might not exist. If it doesn't PHP ***always*** issues a notice.
It's only *after* the notice has been issued that it can be hushed up (by turning off `display_errors` or setting `error_reporting` to not report notices (`~E_NOTICE`).

You're asking for a quick fix:

```
if (isset($_GET['something']))
```

only requires you to add `isset()`. That's quick, and it fixes the issue. Besides: using `isset` is what you *should* do. Always.

---

***Off-topic, but perhaps useful:***
As I've explained in the comments: the best course of action for you now is to fix the issue itself, not ignoring the notices. To that end, a simple script that scans your projects directories for .php files (using `glob`), reads them in and looks for a pattern might prove useful:

```
foreach ($phpFiles as $file)
{
    $code = file_get_contents($file);//read the file
    if (preg_match_all('/if\s*\(\$[^[]+\[[^]]+\]\s*\)/',$code, $matches))
    {//find all usages of "if ($rawVar['offset'])" in code
        echo 'Expressions to check or fix in file: ', $file,':', PHP_EOL, '=>';
        echo implode(PHP_EOL.'=>', $matches[0]), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

run the script, perhaps write the output to a temp file, and set to work. The output should look something like:

```
Expressions to check or fix in file: scriptname.php:
=> if ($_GET['something'])
=> if ($var[123])
```

And so on. It's a workable format, and given time, you might be able to write a script for you to automatically refactor the code, too.
Perhaps a more comprehensive (as in complete) regex to use here would be something like:

```
/if\s*\((\|\||&&|\()?\$[^[]+\[[^]]+\]\s*(\|\||&&|\))?/
```

But this, too, has some caveats still, but it's a start.

---

Adding assignments - I'll do you one more favour: adding code that fixes the issues you get in assignment expressions like `$var = $_GET['something'];`. This can be done automatically, and quite easily, too:

```
foreach ($phpFiles as $file)
{
    $code = file_get_contents($file);//read the file
    $clean = preg_replace(
        '/(\$[^\s]+\s*={1}\s*)(\$[^[]+[^]]+\])\s*;/',
        '$1isset($2) ? $2 : null;',
        $code
    );
    file_put_contents($file, $clean);
}
```

I've tested this code like so:

```
$code = '$foo = 123;
$foo = $_GET["bar"];';
$clean = preg_replace(
    '/(\$[^\s]+\s*={1}\s*)(\$[^[]+[^]]+\])\s*;/',
    '$1isset($2) ? $2 : null;',
    $code
);
echo $clean, PHP_EOL;
```

And it yielded the expected output:

```
$foo = 123;
$foo = isset($_GET["bar"]) ? $_GET["bar"] : null;
```

Combine these two regex's and you should be well on your way to refactoring the code you have...

Comment: Oh, okay. But this happens in like 100 files. So i guess the easy quick-fix would be not to report notices.

Comment: @TobiasLindgreen: That would be ignoring the problem, not fixing it...

Comment: I know :) But in future projects i would know that i should use the isset(). The website worked great before that ;-)

Comment: @TobiasLindgreen: Be aware that notices do cost (they slow you down), and the point of them is to point out possible hidden bugs (typo's in var names etc...) before the cause you grief, which they will in the end. I'll add a _really_ short and kind of brute-force script that'll make your life easier (refactoring-wise)

Comment: I guess i just have to refactor my code then :-)

Comment: @TobiasLindgreen: Check the update, it's crude and incomplete, but it will allow you to isolate the simple cases that require your attention

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at it! But the same error comes if i do like:
$variable = $_GET['something'];

... use the variable above. And if it was empty, i get an error as well. So i guess i'll do it manually.

Comment: @TobiasLindgreen: You could use a regex to check for those cases, too. I'll add that to my answer. Perhaps you might want to consider using [this](https://github.com/EVODelavega/PyPHPScanner/blob/master/Scanner.py). It's the result of my first experiment with python, so it's not great, but it effectively refactors PHP code (either automatically or interactively)

Comment: @TobiasLindgreen: Done, I've added a `preg_replace` call that enables you to replace `$var = $array['access'];` statements with ternary assignments: `$var = isset($array['access']) ? $array['access'] : null;` automatically

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are having the parameter

> something

if it is not, then pass some dummy values to check.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways fix it or hide it.

First option is better and can be done with `isset()` function and it's the best solution.

Another way is to hide notice errors you can do it with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` **I don't recommend this solution**

Answer (score 0):

Will work without notices if you have value of `$_GET['something']` on when checking or it's already defined. Also you have **error reporting on** on your local server not on second server so giving you notices on local server.

```
if ($_GET['something']){
```

if not defined you need to use `isset()` or `empty()` to avoid php notices.

```
if (isset($_GET['something'])){ // will check variable is already set
if (!empty($_GET['something'])){ // will check variable value is not blank or 0
```

or you need to initialize a variable with blank or with some predefined values.

Answer (score 0):

use this may be it helps if(isset(@$_GET[''])){ }

Comment: Using the `isset` language construct will stop PHP from issuing a notice, you don't need the **evil** `@` operator. `@` is an error suppressor. Notices inform you of possible issues, suppressing them is ignoring what could be a bug. It's like advising a child not to listen to its parents when they tell it that fire is hot: it'll get burnt. Don't use `@`