# Undefined index within a PHP path

Tags: php, opencart

Newbie here to OpenCart extension development. I am currently developing a 99Bill (Chinese payment method) payment extension.

Currently, I've added new files to the MVC directories (so, I added files under admin, catalog, etc, where I named my extension bill99, since PHP doesn't allow names that start with numbers).

I was trying to test my extension, but on my OpenCart home page, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: mobile_description in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 20
> Notice: Undefined index: mobile_description in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 20
> Notice: Undefined index: mobile_description in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 20
> Notice: Undefined index: mobile_description in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 20
> Notice: Undefined index: mobile_description in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 20
> Notice: Undefined index: mobile_description in /vagrant/opencart/upload/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 20

I am not quite sure how I triggered it, since I never edited or touched the `product.php` file before. The error appears even if I disable/uninstall my 99Bill extension.

When I navigate to product.php, line 20 simply says:

```
'description'      => $query->row['mobile_description']
```

I have a feeling my error has nothing to do with the product.php file, since I never touched it before, and likely relates to my 99Bill extension. I may have not initialized a class somewhere.

For someone that's had this error before, could you help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

Well: line 20 accesses an array index, doesn't it? Suppose the index doesn't exist, wouldn't the error message you get make sense then? try dumping the contents of `$query->row` or replace what you have now with:

```
'description'      => isset($query->row['mobile_description']) ? $query->row['mobile_description'] : null,
```

As far as *why* you get this notice: [This answer explains that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234215/1230836), and contains some snippets that could help you refactoring your code

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Elias. What I don't quite understand is why, after adding a new extension, I would get this error which I've never received before.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Updated my answer, adding a link to a previous answer of mine that explains where the notice is comming from. Bottom line: it has always been there, but installing a new extension might have changed the ini settings of PHP, or they might have been overridden, keep them at this stricter level, though: notices are there to _help_

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer! I dug a little deeper. Switching back to my master branch (where the 99Bill extension doesn't exist), there will not exist this ***notice***. There probably is something wrong with my 99Bill extension as well since I am unable to "Enable" it.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: not quite: the notice _does_ exist. It's either ignored or not displayed (`error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings are different). No matter what the settings are, the notice is issued internally, so they do cause overhead and slow your code down. Don't ignore them, fix them! Don't blame the extension for forcing PHP to be more strict, blame your code for not being written notice-free